# Plotting histograms on top of each other with legend (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm plotting histograms on top of each other like so:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas


np.random.seed(0)
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(37,2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
df_2 = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(39,2)), columns=['C', 'D'])

df['A'].hist()
df_2['C'].hist()

plt.show()
```

I'm looking for a way to add legends [(e.g. the purple bars = Serie 1 and the blue bars = Serie 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SvCg.png) but I can't find a way to do so. I should probably do something with `ax = df['A'].hist()` but I'm not sure I fully understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following one-liner:

`pd.concat([df['A'],df_2['C']],axis=1).plot(kind='hist')`

Comment: I've modified my minimal reproducible code as it was indeed flawed. I want to plot two columns from two different dataframes. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, please see updated answer.